# How to execute ctrl+r query as-is instead of a match?

Tags: bash, zsh, search, readline, line-editor

Sometimes when I reverse-search cmd in a shell I don't find a correct match and just want to execute search query as it is.

Is there a way in bash/zsh and friends to execute it without discarding input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In zsh, you can use the variables [`LASTSEARCH`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-LASTSEARCH) and [`LASTABORTEDSEARCH`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-LASTABORTEDSEARCH). They're only available inside editor widgets.

An editor widget is a function that has been made into an editor widget with [`zle -N`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-zle) and that is invoked via a key binding. (The key binding can be [`ESC-x`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-execute_002dnamed_002dcmd) — `:` in vi mode.)

For example, the following code binds `ESC-s` to replace the current command line with the last incremental search. If you press `ESC-s` during an incremental search, that's the search in progress (which gets aborted).

```
function set-buffer-last-search { LBUFFER=$LASTSEARCH; RBUFFER=; }
zle -N set-buffer-last-search
bindkey '\es' set-buffer-last-search
```

Comment: I was hoping that it's possible to do so without any customisation, but apparently not.